# How can I define a custom 404 error page for a subdirectory?

Tags: nginx

I have a simple website with some PHP files in two languages: the main language and the translation, let's say Spanish.

I want to show a 404 error page for the main language if someone tries to load an non-existing URL, and a translated 404 error page for non-existing URLs in the /es subdirectory.

This is my config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/example.com;

    location / {
      error_page 404 /404.php;

      try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
      index index.php;
    }

    location /es {
      error_page 404 /es/404.php;

      try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
      index index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri =404;

      include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location @extensionless-php {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }
}
```

It is not working as expected. When loading a non-existing URL (whether in the root or in the /es subdirectory) nginx returns the standard 404 page (the one displaying 404 Not Found).

If I add `error_page 404 /404.php;` in the server block (outside location blocks), then example.com/foo and example.com/es/foo would return the non-translated 404 error page.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of your requests for the non-existent resources ends up at the `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` block where you do not have `error_page` directive at all. If you define your custom error page at the `server` level, that location inherits that page. You can define two PHP handlers (order of `location` blocks matters!):

```
location ~ ^/es.+\.php$ {
    error_page 404 /es/404.php;
    ... # other content is the same as in the question
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    error_page 404 /404.php;
    ... # other content is the same as in the question
}
```

or better use a [`map`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) block like

```
map $uri $errpage {
    ~^/es    /es/404.php;
    default  /404.php;
}
server {
    ...
    error_page 404 $errpage;
}
```